# How to use predict_generator with ImageDataGenerator?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, generator

I'm very new to Keras. I trained a model and would like to predict some images stored in subfolders (like for training). For testing, I want to predict 2 images from 7 classes (subfolders). The test_generator below sees 14 images, but I get 196 predictions. Where is the mistake? Thanks a lot!

```
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        test_dir,
        target_size=(200, 200),
        color_mode="rgb",
        shuffle = "false",
        class_mode='categorical')

filenames = test_generator.filenames
nb_samples = len(filenames)

predict = model.predict_generator(test_generator,nb_samples)
```

Comment: Just a comment: @Ioannis's answer is a more general answer which takes batch_size into account. Note: predict_generator(...) accepts num_of_steps as the second argument which is a number of test samples over batch size. Num_of_steps defines the criteria to stop generator otherwise it will keep in producing or loading a batch of images.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can change the value of `batch_size` in `flow_from_directory` from default value (which is `batch_size=32` ) to `batch_size=1`. Then set the `steps` of `predict_generator` to the total number of your test images. Something like this:

```
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        test_dir,
        target_size=(200, 200),
        color_mode="rgb",
        shuffle = False,
        class_mode='categorical',
        batch_size=1)

filenames = test_generator.filenames
nb_samples = len(filenames)

predict = model.predict_generator(test_generator,steps = nb_samples)
```

Comment: Can someone tell me how do I compute the accuracy after predicting using the `predict_generator`?

Comment: Anyone that is thinking if the model is giving random predictions on your test set: don't forget to set `shuffle = False`. It is there in the OP's post but sometimes you might forget it and the default value is True.

Comment: @MohitMotwani, for computing accuracy, instead of computing it manually, you could use `model.evaluate(test_data, target_data)` or using generator `model.evaluate(test_generator, ...)`. but do not forget to add 'accuracy' for metrics in model.fit()

Comment: is there a possibility to predict each sample separately to measure the inference time?

Comment: Thank you. I was actually missing steps argument. This solved my problem.

Answer (score 10):

Default `batch_size` in generator is 32. If you want to make 1 prediction for every sample of total nb_samples you should devide your nb_samples with the `batch_size`. Thus with a `batch_size` of 7 you only need 14/7=2 steps for your 14 images

```
desired_batch_size=7

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        test_dir,
        target_size=(200, 200),
        color_mode="rgb",
        shuffle = False,
        class_mode='categorical',
        batch_size=desired_batch_size)

filenames = test_generator.filenames
nb_samples = len(filenames)

predict = model.predict_generator(test_generator,steps = 
                                   np.ceil(nb_samples/desired_batch_size))
```

Comment: What if I have a test dataset of size 101, with default batch_size = 32. 
If I set steps = 101 // 32 = 3. I got 96 predictions, but no predictions for the last 5 samples. 
If I set steps = 101 // 32 + 1 = 4. An error will occur.
So what should I do? Use batch_size = 1, for 101 steps? This is not a elegant solution, what if I have a test dataset size of 6234547? Use a batch size of 1 would be very inefficient.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is the inclusion of `nb_samples` in the `predict_generator` which is creating 14 batches of 14 images

```
14*14 = 196
```

Comment: Thank you djk. Unfortunatly, if I remove this argument, I get an errror:

predict_generator() takes at least 3 arguments (2 given)

Comment: So, if I add model.predict_generator(test_generator,1) I get 32 images analyzed (default batch size). This means I should add

 nb_samples = len(filenames) / batch_size
model.predict_generator(test_generator,nb_samples)

Correct? I find it very hard to find good documentation on this.

Best regards,
Mario

Answer (score 2):

Use fit and predict, TensorFlow now supports both the methods with generators.

Answer (score 0):

Just incase someone finds himself here in future wondering why the accuracy score gotten from using model.predict and model.predictor differs. just use the model.predict_generator option regardless of the depracation warning. There seems to be an issue with model.predict when used with generators.