# How to properly save a keras model in R?

Tags: r, keras

I haven't been able to save a keras model, I have been using this code:

```r
save_model_hdf5(model, "F:/Models/1")
```

And I get this **error** message:

```r
#Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords):
#OSError: Unable to create file(unable to open file: name = 'F:\Modelos\1', error = 13,error message = 'Permission denied', flags = 13,o_flags = 302)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Python:**

I use `model.save(filename.hdf5)` to save my models. Note that `model` is an object, e.g. created by `model.compile(...)`. Find a [full example here](https://github.com/Bixi81/Python-ml/blob/master/keras_pretrained_imagerec_binaryclass.py):

```
# Set up model
model = models.Sequential()
...
# Compile model
model.compile(...)
...
# Save model
model.save('C:/savepath/savename.hdf5')
```

It is possible to load the model again, e.g. [to make predictions as outlined here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55991598/9524424).

```
# Load model
model = load_model('C:/savepath/savename.hdf5')
```

**R:**

In R, saving models works a little different:

```
# Set up a model
model <- create_model()
...
# Fit the model
model %>% fit()
...
# Save the model
model %>% save_model_hdf5("C:/savepath/savename.hdf5")
```

Or alternatively (without infix operator `%>%` which is not part of base R):

```
save_model_hdf5(model, "C:/savepath/savename.hdf5")
```

Comment: save_model_hdf5(model, "F:/Models/1/model.hdf5")