# Keras how to evaluate a single image once model has been fit

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm just learning Keras now and I followed a tutorial for creating an image classification model which was quite good and worked well.

Now, however, I want to take it a step further and feed it one image at a time and have it try to classify it. I think this should be fairly simple in concept,  but I'm probably misunderstanding something fundamental.

So Here is my model:

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(32,(3,3), input_shape=x_train.shape[1:], padding='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3,3), padding='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(.2))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
```

So when I ran this I also used:

```
model.save_weights('cif_weights.h5')
model.save('cif_model.h5')
```

Now I want to load these back into a different script and have it load a single image, classify it and spit out what it thinks it is.

I thought initially that you'd use model.evaluate(xtest, ytest) and just have that be 1 image of xtest data and ytest data but that gives me 1 loss and 1 accuracy for the model overall and doesn't tell me an actual classification.

For reference, I'm using the CIFAR-10 data set for training so it's those 10 different classes.

If anyone can point me somewhere where that is explained or even in the Keras documentation.

Comment: This should work if you use an data generator: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52270177/how-to-use-predict-generator-on-new-images-keras/55991598#55991598

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I apologize if I am misunderstanding your question, but I interpret you to be asking how to load your trained and saved model 'cif_weights.h5' into another python script where you load an image and use said model to classify said image.

Using your model, make sure to import **load_model** from keras into your new script.

Next, get the image you want to predict on and make it of the same dimensions as what the network accepted.

So say your network trained on images of 50x50 pixels, you will have to transform your image into a numpy array of 1x50x50.

This can be done by first loading the image you want to predict on, say the variable is **img**, and it is a 100x100 numpy array. use:

```
img.reshape(50,50) # replace 50,50 with whatever dimensions your network was trained on
```

Then add a first dimension to the array :

```
img = img[numpy.newaxis,:,:]
```

then finally you can load your model and make a prediction:

```
model=load_model('cif_weights.h5')
prediction = model.predict(img)
```

this new "prediction" we get will be a vector of length 10, representing what the model predicts your new images classification to be. If you want to find what the weights predict on this image directly, you can use

```
numpy.argmax(prediction)
```

and that will return the class that the network predicts the image belongs to based on current weights.

Comment: Hi George, thanks, this put me on the right track. In the end I used OpenCV to preprocess the individual images as doing a generic reshape on the numpy array wouldn't work initially. Thanks! Redcoatwright